# change single backgroundcolor on click with only one function

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have this function in react native, this function change all background colors on the click, there's a way i can change one div color without making multiple functions?

```js
function lastTouches() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const Press1 = () => setActive(!active);

    const buttonTextStyle = {
        color: active ? 'green' : 'red'
    };

    return (
        <> // JSX expressions must have one parent element.
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={Press1}>
                    <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
                        Change Color 1
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={Press1}>
                    <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
                        Change Color 2
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={Press1}>
                    <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
                        Change Color 3
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}

export default lastTouches;
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution, you can create a component for item to display, which handle the active state. So, state will be separate for each items like this :

```js
function BoxItem (props) {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

    const toggleActive = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
    }

    const buttonTextStyle = {
        color: active ? 'green' : 'red'
    };

    return (
        <Box>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleActive}>
                <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
                    {props.title}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Box>
    )
}

function lastTouches() {
    return (
        <>
            <BoxItem title="Change Color 1" />
            <BoxItem title="Change Color 2" />
            <BoxItem title="Change Color 2" />
        </>
    );
}

export default lastTouches;
```

On above solution each item contains it's own `active` state and will be toggled whenever item is clicked.

Second way is, use array to store `active` status for multiple item, and use index of unique key to identify the item like this :

```js
function lastTouches() {
    const [activeItems, setActiveItems] = useState([]);

    const toggleItem = (id) => {
        if (activeItems.indexOf(id) > -1) {
            setActiveItems(activeItems.filter((item) => item !== id));
        } else {
            setActiveItems([...activeItems, id]);
        }
    }

    const activeButtonStyle = {
        color: 'green',
    };

    const deactiveButtonStyle = {
        color: 'red'
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleItem("item1")}>
                    <Text style={activeItems.indexOf("item1") > -1 ? activeButtonStyle : deactiveButtonStyle}>
                        Change Color 1
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleItem("item2")}>
                    <Text style={activeItems.indexOf("item2") > -1 ? activeButtonStyle : deactiveButtonStyle}>
                        Change Color 2
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleItem("item3")}>
                    <Text style={activeItems.indexOf("item3") > -1 ? activeButtonStyle : deactiveButtonStyle}>
                        Change Color 3
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}

export default lastTouches;
```